# High performance endorsement

Tags: multi-engine, cfi

If I am a Commercial multi rated pilot with high performance and CFI. But not CFII or MEI, can I give a high performance endorsement to another commercial multi rated pilot in a multi engine?

The thought being since we are both multi rated, an MEI is not needed. But I am not 100% certain on that.

Comment: I'm just curious, how is it possible to become a commercial multi-engine rated pilot without a high performance endorsement?  Is there a CFR that specifies HP of each individual engine must be >200?  (I would have presumed that a twin with a couple 120s would be considered 200+HP, and therefore high performance...)

Comment: @MichaelHall   FAR 61.31(f) shown below in the first answer says *"(an airplane with **an engine** of more than 200 horsepower)*. –

Comment: @757toga, yeah I see that, and while it's clear enough for a SE, it isn't how any "normal" person would write a reg for ME.  For a multi one would chose an example such as "an airplane with **any** engine of more than 200 HP." or "an airplane with engine**s** of more than 200 HP **each**."

Comment: @MichaelHall. That makes sense to me and would be much clearer.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.

[FAR §61.31(f) states](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.31) (**emphasis** mine):

> **(1)** Except as provided in paragraph (f)(2) of this section, no person may act as pilot in command of a high-performance airplane (an airplane with an engine of more than 200 horsepower), unless the person has -
>
> > **(i)** Received and logged ground and flight training from an **authorized instructor** in a high-performance airplane, or in a full flight simulator or flight training device that is representative of a high-performance airplane, and has been found proficient in the operation and systems of the airplane; and
> >
> > **(ii)** Received a one-time endorsement in the pilot's logbook from an **authorized instructor** who certifies the person is proficient to operate a high-performance airplane.

[FAR §61.1(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.1) defines "authorized instructor" as (**emphasis** mine):

> **(i)** A person who holds a ground instructor certificate issued under part 61 of this chapter and is in compliance with § 61.217, when conducting ground training in accordance with the privileges and limitations of his or her ground instructor certificate;
>
> **(ii)** A person who holds a flight instructor certificate issued under part 61 of this chapter and is in compliance with § 61.197, when conducting ground training or flight training **in accordance with the privileges and limitations of his or her flight instructor certificate**; or
>
> **(iii)** A person authorized by the Administrator to provide ground training or flight training under part 61, 121, 135, or 142 of this chapter when conducting ground training or flight training in accordance with that authority.

Because you're not an "authorized instructor" in a multi-engine airplane, you can't give the training required by §61.31(f)(1)(i), nor can you use a multi-engine airplane to "certify" another pilot's proficiency under §61.31(f)(1)(ii).

Your creative thinking seems reasonable on the surface, but the verbiage is pretty clear here, and the FAA and courts are known to interpret the regulations very conservatively. You could always ask the FSDO for an official interpretation (if you do, please come back and post the answer here for us!).

Until then, I suppose you'll need to find either an MEI or a single to fly in.

Answer (score 0):

Negative.  See §61.195(b)(1-2)

> Except as provided in paragraph (c) of this section, a flight
> instructor may not conduct flight training in any aircraft unless the
> flight instructor:
>
> (1) Holds a flight instructor certificate with the applicable category
> and class rating;
>
> (2) Holds a pilot certificate with the applicable category and class
> rating; and
>
> (3) Meets the requirements of paragraph (e) of this section, if
> applicable.

This includes logbook endorsements as well for particular aircraft category and class.

Now it is possible to give the other person a high-performance endorsement if the training is conducted in an aircraft category and class listed on your flight instructor certificate.  As I understand it, there is no distinction between a high-performance, single engine airplane in a high performance, multi-engine airplane in re to training requirements to meet §61.31(f).